# Need help in navigating view controllers

Tags: ios

I am developing one small iOS app, and am facing a problem in navigation of view controllers.
This is my code (I got it from the net):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailsViewController *page = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    CGRect theFrame = page.view.frame;
    theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
    page.view.frame = theFrame;
    theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
    page.view.frame = theFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  

    [self.view addSubview:page.view];
 }
```

By which I can navigate to new view controller. This is working fine but I now need to come back to my original controller upon tapping of a button. This is where I am stuck and I am not using any navigation controllers and am new to iOS.
If any of you have an idea of how this can be done in a better way it would be great to hear it!

Comment: do u want to set animation like Navigation push pop?

Comment: @iPatel he not using navigationController

Comment: he also said  i am stuck and i am not using any navigation controllers please read

Comment: @NitinGohel- yes bro. you are right :)

Comment: @Gaurav you have to give response about answer that people who give ur question's answer.

Comment: Pretty much everything about this code snippet is bad -- it adds the view of another controller to your view without making it a child view controller. It uses animations that have not been recommended since iOS 4 (you should be using block based animations). This is a very simple thing to do, in a variety of ways. I suggest you study the documentation (especially the two guides linked to at the top of the UIViewController Class Reference), and learn how to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Go to nextview controller used this code..

```
ViewController * v=[[ViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:YES];
```

back on privous main view controller used this code

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: no i am not using navigationController its all view controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give push and pop animation then you have to make current view Controller to make root controller of Navigation Controller.

And then after this ::

**A_ViewController**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    B_ViewContorller *page = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:page animated:YES];
}
```

**B_ViewController**
After reaching to B_ViewController and want to back to A_ViewController

Just Use this if you are not using default navigationBar

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

One of the advantage to use default navigation Bar that it gives you default back button. I recommended to use Default navigation-bar.